# Php not working on Mac OS 10.13

Tags: php, macos, apache

After I tried (stupidly) to install PHP through Homebrew, I don't know what I did but now, after I rolled back to PHP 7.1, now it doesn't work anymore on my machine. When I try to see a PHP page through Safari, it shows the code.

I've already de-commented every LoadModule in `httpd.conf` without any success. I've already tried to restart also `apachectl` and it didn't work.

Comment: what do you see when you enter `php -v` into terminal?

Comment: how about mamp?

Comment: @WebCode.ie 
`PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2018 13:14:42) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies`

Comment: @Matheus I considered it, however It's the last solution. I just want to understand WHY now it doesn't work instead of before that worked perfectly